# Extract all text in between two nodes using xpath for websrcaping?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

```
       <div class="jokeContent">
            <h2 style="color:#369;">Can I be Frank</h2>
            What did Ellen Degeneres say to Kathy Lee? 
           <p></p> <p>Can I be Frank with you? </p> 
           <p>Submitted by Calamjo</p> 
           <p>Edited by Curtis</p>      
       <div align="right" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">#joke <a href="http://www.jokesoftheday.net/tag/short-jokes/">#short</a> </div>
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```

So I am trying to extract all text after the <\h2> and before the              [div aign = "right" style=...] nodes.
What I have tried so far:

```
    jokes = response.xpath('//div[@class="jokeContent"]')
    for joke in jokes:
        text = joke.xpath('text()[normalize-space()]').extract()]
        if len(text) > 0:
            yield text
```

This works to some extend, but the website is inconsistent in the html and  sometimes the text is embedded in  <.p> TEXT <\p> and sometimes in  <.br> TEXT <\br> or just TEXT.
So I thought just extracting everything after the header and before the style node might make sense and then the filtering can be done afterwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a literal xpath of what you are describing, it could be something like:

```
In [1]: sel.xpath("//h2/following-sibling::*[not(self::div) and not(preceding-sibling::div)]//text()").extract()
Out[1]: [u'Can I be Frank with you? ', u'Submitted by Calamjo', u'Edited by Curtis']
```

But there's probably a more logical, cleaner conclusion:

```
In [2]: sel.xpath("//h2/following-sibling::p//text()").extract()
Out[2]: [u'Can I be Frank with you? ', u'Submitted by Calamjo', u'Edited by Curtis']
```

This is just selecting paragraph tags. You said the paragraph tags might be something else and you can match several different tags with `self::tag` specification:

```
In [3]: sel.xpath("//h2/following-sibling::*[self::p or self::br]//text()").extract()
Out[3]: [u'Can I be Frank with you? ', u'Submitted by Calamjo', u'Edited by Curtis']
```

Edit: apparently I missed the text under the div itself. This can be ammended with `|` - or selector:

```
In [3]: sel.xpath("//h2/../text()[normalize-space(.)] | //h2/../p//text()").extract()
Out[3]: 
[u'\n            What did Ellen Degeneres say to Kathy Lee? \n           ',
 u'Can I be Frank with you? ',
 u'Submitted by Calamjo',
 u'Edited by Curtis']
```

`normalize-space(.)` is there only to get rid of text values that contain no text (e.g. '   \n').
You can append the first part of this xpath to any of the above and you'd get similar results.

Comment: Okay, I see this works for every defined tag but in the above example the sentence ( What did Ellen Degeneres say to Kathy Lee? ) is lacking tags. What could be a smart way of getting this as well? (That was why I thought just getting everything in between the div classes might be useful.

Comment: @OliverEbrle oh sorry I totally missed that. See my edit for how to get that bit too.

Comment: Okay great this solves some of my problems but of course new show up: So e.g. on this page (http://www.jokesoftheday.net/tag/short-jokes/6) I want to scrap all jokes using joke.xpath(".//h2/../text()[normalize-space(.)] | .//h2/../p//text()").extract() but some h2 headlines get extracted as well due to the inconsistent site format. E.g. <h2 style="color:#369;"><p>“I told the knight th</p></h2> and here using the xpath the ' told the knight th' is extractet in addition to the full (desired) text.

Comment: I guess it is due to the <\p> in the headline? But I do not fully understand why it gets extracted because the xpath is extracting everything after the h2 tag, no?